# Prisma delete row in database if a linked field (by relation) is == something

Tags: javascript, prisma

The following query deletes a row in a database if the teamId is found. However, I don't want anyone inside of a team to be able to delete it.

To fix this, we have `roles` in the team. Can I add a check to this query to say ``delete `where id: teamId if TeamMember: {some: {userId: userId, role: "owner"}`

Essentially, we have a linked table called `teamMembers`, and I want to delete the team if the userId in teamMembers has the role `owner`.

Hopefully this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appriciated. I know I could do a separate query checking if the specified userId is an owner, but it would be nicer if it could be done in one query.

```js
  await prisma.team
    .delete({
      where: {
        id: teamId,
      },
    })
```

Comment: Have you looked at adding an [`AND` condition](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#and) to your `where`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using this :)

Answer (score 0):

To delete a user based on their unique ID and role, you can modify the Prisma delete statement like this:

```
await prisma.team.deleteMany({
  where: {
    id: teamId,
    teamMembers: {
      some: {
        userId: userId,
        role: 'owner',
      },
    },
  },
});
```